# Folder Drag and Drop that works with Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer, upload, drag-and-drop

We have a need to **upload multiple files** to our server while **preserving directory structure**. I am looking for a client-side functionality that will allow me to to do **drag and drop** of a **folder**. I have successfully accomplished this with Chrome using **webkitdirectory** in an  tag.
I have tried a few libraries (FileDrop.js, DropZone.js ...) but I have not been able to drag and drop folders in IE.
I would prefer to have a solution that works with all browsers but our clients are now heavily concentrated in **IE** and **Chrome**.
We would be open to using a third party tool that would not involve sending data to a 'cloud' server.

Comment: go with this http://filedropjs.org/

Comment: I have tried using some of the examples. Folder drop only appears to work in Chrome

Answer (score 1):

You can look at http://www.rajeshsegu.com/2012/08/html5-drag-and-drop-a-folder

This link have some details that you are looking for

Comment: I have tried his approach. Folder drop only works in Chrome

Comment: ohh ok... let me try some solution for IE